# Automated Wordpress install php [Browser Side]

Tags: php, wordpress

I Make alot of wordpress sites so I decided to start working on a simple automated script on my localhost, where I simply fill in a form, and it builds the wordpress site.

The form looks like below >

```
    <label>MagicWord<br /><input type="text" name="magicword"></label>
    <label>Email Address<br /><input type="text" name="email" ></label>
    <label>Site Title<br /><input type="text" name="title"></label>
    <label>Wp-Admin User<br /><input type="text" name="username" ></label>
    <label>Wp-Admin Password<br /><input type="password" name="password" ></label>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Let Get Wordpressing!">
```

The form posts to the setup.php.
The "magicword" is just the name of the folder + Database to be created.
The setup script makes the database, Creates the folder, downloads latest wordpress zip, unzips and places it in the folder that has been created.

But I am struggling to work out how to do the wordpress install setup but using the form inputs. There are alot of cli awnsers but I can't work out how I would go about doing it for web.

```
$magicword = $_POST["magicword"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sitetitle = $_POST["title"];
$wpadminuser = $_POST["username"];
$wpadminpass = $_POST["password"];

define('ABSPATH', $WEBROOT);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'wp-content/');
define('WPINC', 'wp-includes');
define( 'WP_LANG_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/languages' );

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
define('DB_NAME', $MYSQLDB);
define('DB_USER', $MYSQLUSER);
define('DB_PASSWORD', $MYSQLPWD);
define('DB_HOST', $MYSQLHOST);

$_GET['step'] = 2;
$_POST['weblog_title'] = $sitetitle;
$_POST['user_name'] = $wpadminuser;
$_POST['admin_email'] = $email;
$_POST['blog_public'] = true;
$_POST['admin_password'] = $wpadminpass;

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/install.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-walker.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
```

I see this solution, as the cli, but i cant seem to work out how id go about adding my form entries to these and then going through the install.

This is the link to the code i ref above: https://www.markomedia.com.au/install-wordpress-in-less-than-a-minute/

**To Sum up what I'm looking to do**

Automate the wordpress setup and installation with form entries and a php script.

---

Things I've looked into.
I have looked at the WP CLI, But I'm not 100% sure how i could go about integrating that into the localhost or if i actually can?

Thank you very much In advance

EDIT

Ive managed to make the config file.

```
$file = "../". $magicword ."/wp-config.php";

$current = file_put_contents($file);
$current .= "<?php\n";

$current .= "// @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php";
$current .= "// @package WordPress";

$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpres_". $magicword ."' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_USER', 'wordpres' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'D9td2yp7' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );\n\n\n";

$explode = explode("\n", $secretkeys);
$current .= "\n". $explode[0];
$current .= "\n". $explode[1];
$current .= "\n". $explode[2];
$current .= "\n". $explode[3];
$current .= "\n". $explode[4];
$current .= "\n". $explode[5];
$current .= "\n". $explode[6];
$current .= "\n". $explode[7];

$current .= "\n\n\n\$table_prefix = 'wordpres_';";
$current .= "\n\ndefine( 'WP_DEBUG', false );";

$current .= "\n\nif ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {";
$current .= "\n   define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );";
$current .= "\n}\n\nrequire_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );";

$current .= "?>";

file_put_contents($file, $current);

chmod("../". $magicword ."/wp-config.php", 0666);
```

How ever when i then try the following code:

```
define( 'WP_INSTALLING', true );

require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-load.php" );
require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php" );
require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-includes/wp-db.php" );

wp_install( $sitetitle, $wpadminuser, $email, "1", '', $wpadminpass, "en_GB");

$directory = "http://www.designerdev.co.uk/~wordpres/". $magicword . "/";
$protocol = ! is_ssl() ? 'http' : 'https';
$get = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/index.php/wp-admin/install.php?action=install_wp';
$dir = str_replace( '../', '', $directory );
$link = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace( $get, $dir, $link );
$url = trim( $url, '/' );
update_option( 'siteurl', $url );
update_option( 'home', $url );
```

To set up the db install it causes an odd error where it installs wordpress in the root outside of the sub folder wordpress

Comment: so.. instead of filling out a form to install, you get them to fill out a form? o.O

Comment: @treyBake well when you say it like that i sound stupid <_< .... it just means i can add 3 things to a form, and it installs wordpress completely. I know it can be done in cli, But i want to see if i can do it in browser. And its not them its purely for me.

Comment: @treyBake It's not for other people really its purely jsut for me. Although once I've done it i will share the entire script on my github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully automated wordpress. I'll share the link on my github soon.

```
$file = "../". $magicword ."/wp-config.php";

$current = file_put_contents($file);

$current .= "<?php\n";

$current .= "// @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php";
$current .= "// @package WordPress";

$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpres_". $magicword ."' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_USER', 'wordpres' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'D9td2yp7' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );";
$current .= "\ndefine( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );\n\n\n";

$explode = explode("\n", $secretkeys);
$current .= "\n". $explode[0];
$current .= "\n". $explode[1];
$current .= "\n". $explode[2];
$current .= "\n". $explode[3];
$current .= "\n". $explode[4];
$current .= "\n". $explode[5];
$current .= "\n". $explode[6];
$current .= "\n". $explode[7];

$current .= "\n\n\n\$table_prefix = 'wordpres_';";
$current .= "\n\ndefine( 'WP_DEBUG', false );";

$current .= "\n\nif ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {";
$current .= "\n   define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );";
$current .= "\n}\n\nrequire_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );";

$current .= "?>";

file_put_contents($file, $current);

define( 'WP_INSTALLING', true );

require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-load.php" );
require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php" );
require_once("../". $magicword ."/wp-includes/wp-db.php" );

wp_install( $sitetitle, $wpadminuser, $email, "1", '', $wpadminpass, "en_GB");


$url = location;
update_option( 'siteurl', $url );
update_option( 'home', $url );
```

Comment: I am also automating this using salt stack . Just wanted to check with you where do you put the above config, in which file, and how do you execute this , I am new to php. apologies for asking this questions

Comment: @Manmohan Mirkar This code is for generating the /wp-config.php i have since written a better system that just takes the original perinstalled version and changes what I need it to. Current wordpress is super easy to automate and pretty much all of the content already exists. All you have to do is download wordpress, unzip in the FTP and then add users to the db and activate the wp scripts its super easy

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways on how to automate the installation of WordPress on a server. One popular way is to use a tool like WP-CLI to handle the installation from the command line. Another option is to use a script like WordPress Automatic Installer, which can automate the entire process from start to finish.

For folks who are comfortable working with PHP, there is also a PHP-based solution that can be used to install WordPress automatically. This approach requires a bit more work than the others, but it can be a good option for those who are comfortable with PHP and want more control over the process.

No matter which approach you choose, automating the installation of WordPress can save you a lot of time and hassle. And once you have it up and running, you can focus on more important things, like creating great content and building your audience.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).